# How do I fire an intent to start a flv or swf to Flash Player 10.1?

Tags: java, android, flash, flv

I have a bunch of **flv video** files stored on a **media server**, and I am trying to get them to launch in the flash player. Have been looking around but haven't found much help. I have downloaded the flv file into temporary storage, and try passing it using an `intent`. This is what my code looks like (from what I have seen on the net):

```
try{
  URL urlLink = new URL("http://206.188.19.131/p4p101.flv");

  // Serve the file
  InputStream in = urlLink.openStream();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/tempFlash.flv");
  byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024]; // 4K buffer
  int bytesRead;
  while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  fos.close();
  in.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}

try{
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  File file = new File("/sdcard/tempFlash.flv");
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "flash/*");
  startActivity(intent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No apps to launch activity", 1000);
  toast.show();
}
```

Comment: you just need to add spaces before the lines in your code so that it ends up properly formatted - doing this will increase the likelihood of your question being answered.

Comment: so you are trying to play flv video with java? let me know if you need a solution in actionscript.

Comment: yah you can edit your post and select all the stuff in the text area that's code and click the code button above the text area and it'll put extra 4 spaces at the beginning of each line so it knows it's code, I don't think it's very intuitive but whatever it works.  I don't know that i can help on this one anyhow though...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help: 
http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications
playing FLV on Android using flash player inside a webview

Answer (score 0):

may be try to change your mimetype:
video/x-flv or flv-application/octet-stream